# mobile listview filter always visible when scroll

Tags: listview, mobile, user-interface, filter, kendo-ui

With KENDO UI MOBILE How is it possible to have filter box always visible when I scroll down the content?

```
 function mobileListViewEndlessScrolling() {
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                pageSize: 40,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=1&page=1&q=koi", // the remove service url
                        dataType: "jsonp" // JSONP (JSON with padding) is required for cross-domain AJAX

                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options) {
                        var filter = options.filter ? options.filter.filters[0].value : "";
                        var parameters = {
                            q: filter, //additional parameters sent to the remote service
                            rpp: options.pageSize,
                            page: options.page //next page
                        }

                        return parameters;
                    }
                    //http://localhost:50833/Service1.svc/GetLocalita.json?q=&rpp=10&page=1
                },
                schema: { // describe the result format
                    data: "results" // the data which the data source will be bound to is in the "results" field
                }
            });

            $("#endless-scrolling").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: $("#endless-scrolling-template").text(),
                filterable: true,
                endlessScroll: true,
                scrollTreshold: 30 //treshold in pixels
            });
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution given by Kendo :) Good luck!

http://dojo.telerik.com/afosu

Answer (score 0):

I also was trying to implement the same behavior and checked with Kendo support. They informed me that as of today such behavior is not supported. It wont even work with   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  CSS applied to the List . I think they implement the behaviour like this because the iOS list behaves the same way.  Anyway way its good to have a static filter so that u dont have to scroll up to filter the list.